# MongoDB MapReduce returning unexpected results and grouping twice

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, grouping

I am using MongoDB and wanted to count the number of occurrences of each distinct "concatenated_handles" (a field with type string) in a collection.

I had to also sort according to the number of occurrences, so I decided to use mapreduce, it was all going good but suddenly I started getting unexpected results and I changed no code whatsoever

This is my map :

```
function() { emit(this.concatenated_handles, { count: 1}); }
```

This is the reduce :

```
r = function(key, values) { var result = {count : 0}; values.forEach(function(value) { result.count++; }); return result; }
```

Its returning correct values for some fields, while incorrect for others. I logged the output, and here it is (showing only fields which are bugged)

```
    msdhoni#yuvstrong12:0
    msdhoni#yuvstrong12:1
    msdhoni#yuvstrong12:2
    ....
    ...
    msdhoni#yuvstrong12:255
    msdhoni#yuvstrong12:256
    musclenerd#pod2g:0
    musclenerd#pod2g:1
```

This field starts grouping again after a few other lines (all re-groupings are towards the end)

```
justinbieber#pattiemallette:0
justinbieber#pattiemallette:1
justinbieber#pattiemallette:2
justinbieber#pattiemallette:3
justinbieber#scooterbraun:0
justinbieber#scooterbraun:1
justinbieber#scooterbraun:2
kaleycuoco#kunalnayyar:0
kaleycuoco#kunalnayyar:1
kaleycuoco#kunalnayyar:2
kaleycuoco#kunalnayyar:3
kaleycuoco#kunalnayyar:4
kaleycuoco#kunalnayyar:5
msdhoni#yuvstrong12:0
msdhoni#yuvstrong12:1
msdhoni#yuvstrong12:2
```

All the above fields are REGROUPED towards the end. They seem to be the same but they grouped twice and hence the unexpected results. And this does not happen with all the records.

Where am I going wrong? The group field is a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, MongoDB can call MapReduce recursively or in parts. So, the reduce function should be idempotent.

You would say my reduce function's idempotent too, since the structure of the values map is emitting and the structure of the values reduce is returning is the same. However, one very important point to note is - Whenever calls are made iteratively, the result of the first call will be passed as an input to the second call.

So in my case with this reduce :

```
r = function(key, values) { var result = {count : 0}; values.forEach(function(value) { result.count++; }); return result; }
```

Every subsequent call for the same key would start the increment with 0 and add 1 instead of adding the count that was passed to it from the previous iteration as value.count

So instead of doing

```
result.count++;
```

I should have been doing

```
result.count += value.count;
```

So that every call uses the count till the previous call.

I am not sure if I explained this correctly, but it is well documented here (under More Technical Explanation) :

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce